# How to configure Cachelib properly to use NVME

Tags: c++, caching

CacheLib is a Meta library that allows us to configure hybrid cache, we start using the DRAM and when there is a need for eviction -> we evict first to the NVME.
The idea is to have more cheep space for the cache.

This is how I configured cache lib:

```
// Big hash configurations
static int gBigHashSizePct = GetUintFromEnv("NVME_BIGHASH_SIZE_PCT"); // bigHashSizePct (0-100), the % of the file that bigHash will use
static int gBigHashSmallItemMaxSize = GetUintFromEnv("NVME_BIGHASH_SMALL_ITEM_MAX_SIZE"); // bigHashSmallItemMaxSize must be smaller then bucket size which is 4096 by default
static int gBigHashBucketSize = GetUintFromEnv("NVME_BIGHASH_BUCKET_SIZE"); // default 4096
static int gBigHashBucketBfSize = GetUintFromEnv("NVME_BIGHASH_BLOOM_FILTER_PER_BUCKET_SIZE"); //  bloom filter size per bucket, default is 8


// Allow control for admission probability to Nvme
float gAdmissionProbability = std::stof(std::getenv("NVME_ADDMISSION_PROBABILITY")); // should be 0 - 1

// Allow control on max msg in and max msg out sizes
static int gMaxGrpcRecivedSize = GetUintFromEnv("MAX_GRPC_MSG_RECIVED_SIZE"); // Default will be 50 mb (50000000)
static int gMaxGrpcSendSize = GetUintFromEnv("MAX_GRPC_MSG_SEND_SIZE"); // Default will be 50 mb (50000000)


static uint32_t gMaxChainedSize = GetUintFromEnv("MAX_CHAINED_SIZE"); // ((1024*1024*4) - 8) 4 MB - is the default, we use 8 bytes less then the default
static uint64_t gCacheRamSize = InitgCacheSize("CACHE_RAM_SIZE"); // 1GB = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
static uint32_t gNumbersOfItemsWePlanToCache = GetUintFromEnv("NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_CACHE"); // 100 * 100 * 4000 [we plan to support 100 customers with 100 videows each]
static uint64_t gCacheSize =  InitgCacheSize("CACHE_NVME_SIZE"); // the nvme cache size
static uint32_t gBlockSize = GetUintFromEnv("BLOCK_SIZE"); // default 4096
static uint32_t gRegionSize = GetUintFromEnv("REGION_SIZE"); // 16 * 1024 * 1024
static std::string gCacheFilePath = std::getenv("CACHE_FILE");

using Cache = cachelib::LruAllocator; // or Lru2QAllocator, or TinyLFUAllocator
using CacheConfig = typename Cache::Config;
using CacheKey = typename Cache::Key;
using CacheReadHandle = typename Cache::ReadHandle;

// Global cache object and a default cache pool
std::unique_ptr<Cache> gCache_;
cachelib::PoolId defaultPool_;

    // Ram config
    CacheConfig config;
    config
    .setCacheSize(gCacheRamSize) // 1GB = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
    .setCacheName("My Case")
    .setAccessConfig(gNumbersOfItemsWePlanToCache) // assuming caching 20 = {25 /* bucket power */, 10 /* lock power */})
                                                    // million items
    .validate(); // will throw if bad config
            
    // Hybrid config (Ram 6 Nvme)
    //CacheConfig lruConfig;
    Cache::NvmCacheConfig nvmConfig;
    nvmConfig.navyConfig.setBlockSize(gBlockSize); // Default is 4096 - Device block size in bytes (minimum IO granularity)
    nvmConfig.navyConfig.setSimpleFile(gCacheFilePath,
                                gCacheSize,         /*fileSize*/
                                false           /*truncateFile*/);

    // Set admission policy
    nvmConfig.navyConfig.enableRandomAdmPolicy().setAdmProbability(gAdmissionProbability); // a float number that decides Acceptance probability. The value has to be in the range of [0, 1].

    // Engine Settings:

    // Block Cache: - caches objects that are larger than KBs in size 
    // Set the block cache - Large Object Cache - caches objects that are larger than KBs in size 
    nvmConfig.navyConfig.blockCache().setRegionSize(gRegionSize);

    // Set the Small Object Cache - caches objects that are 100s of bytes
    nvmConfig.navyConfig.bigHash()
      .setSizePctAndMaxItemSize(gBigHashSizePct, gBigHashSmallItemMaxSize) // bigHashSizePct (0-100), the % of the file that bigHash will use , bigHashSmallItemMaxSize must be smaller then bucket size which is 4096 by default
      .setBucketSize(gBigHashBucketSize)
      .setBucketBfSize(gBigHashBucketBfSize); // bloom filter size per bucket, default is 8


    // make the cache actually hybrid
    config.enableNvmCache(nvmConfig).validate();

    // Try to ease up on the ssd burning rate by adding admission rate to the cache as a whole
    // This will accept to the cache only if there where 2 accurance in the time frame
    //auto policy = std::make_shared<cachelib::RejectFirstAP<facebook::cachelib::LruAllocator>>();
    //config.setNvmCacheAdmissionPolicy(std::move(policy));

    gCache_ = std::make_unique<Cache>(config);
    //gCache_ = std::make_unique<Cache>(lruConfig);
    
    defaultPool_ =  gCache_->addPool("default", gCache_->getCacheMemoryStats().ramCacheSize);
```

This is the environment variables:

```
environment:
      - CACHE_RAM_SIZE=107374182 # 100mb
      - CACHE_NVME_SIZE=858993459200 # 1GB = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, we will use *800gb*
      - BLOCK_SIZE=4096 #  default 4096
      - NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_CACHE=40000000 # 100 * 100 * 4000 [we plan to support 100 customers with 100 videos each]
      - REGION_SIZE=16777216 # Not sure what is this - keep it as default: 16 * 1024 * 1024
      - CACHE_FILE=/nvmeCache/nvmeCache # The path to file we use for nvme cache
      - DBG=True # To remove debug - we should comment DBG all together
      - MAX_CHAINED_SIZE=1048568 # The size of each chained element, currently we set it to (1024*1024*1)-8 (1MB -8 bytes) which efectively set the max size of cacheable item to ~255gb 
      - MAX_GRPC_MSG_RECIVED_SIZE=50000000 # 50mb
      - MAX_GRPC_MSG_SEND_SIZE=50000000 # 50mb
      - NVME_ADDMISSION_PROBABILITY=0.9 # This set what is the probability we will add object to nvme cache
      - NVME_BIGHASH_SIZE_PCT=30 # (0-100), the % of the file that bigHash will use
      - NVME_BIGHASH_SMALL_ITEM_MAX_SIZE=4052 # bigHashSmallItemMaxSize must be smaller then bucket size which is 4096 by default
      - NVME_BIGHASH_BUCKET_SIZE=4096 #default 4096
      - NVME_BIGHASH_BLOOM_FILTER_PER_BUCKET_SIZE=8 # bloom filter size per bucket, default is 8
```

When I test it, I send many chanks of information (larger then 100mb) and expect that the eviction will be to the NVME and I will be able to get all of them back.

This is my test code (c#):

```
// Test multiple writes
for (int i = 33; i < 125; i ++)
{
    string key = new string((char)i, 32);
    string value = new string((char)i, 50000000 - 50);
    IntType res = await client.PutAsync(new StoreRequest { Key = key, Value = value });
    if (res.Res != 1)
    {
        bool aaa = false;
    }

    // Make sure we X3 hits
    await client.GetAsync(new Request { Key = key });
    await client.GetAsync(new Request { Key = key });
    await client.GetAsync(new Request { Key = key });
}

// Test multiple reads
for (int i = 33; i < 125; i++)
{
    string key = new string((char)i, 32);
    Response res = await client.GetAsync(new Request { Key = key });
    if (res.Value == null || res.Value.Length < 50000000 - 50)
    {
          // Im expects to never be here - all the cache should be written to the NVME
        bool error = true;
    }
}
```

But when I test this, I get only the results of the keys `124,125` (i.e., 100mb is cached only).

What do I do rung? I appreciate any help here.

Comment: Not sure that last bit of code is C++. May be useful to tag properly.